# How display Chinese characters properly in tabulate

Tags: python-3.x, tabulate

I use the tabulate to display some data which has Chinese characters. However the output isn't organized.

```py
from tabulate import tabulate
data = [ ["北京理工大学", "985", 2000],
         ["清华大学", "985", 3000],
         ["大连理工大学", "985", 4000],
         ["深圳大学", "211", 2000],
         ["沈阳大学", "省本", 2000],
    ]
print(tabulate(data, tablefmt="grid"))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h12YB.png)

Comment: Just in case!, It happens because tabulate module is especially done for Command Line Interface (CLI) like Terminal (linux), cmd (windows) or Python command line (it says here: https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/), so characters like Chinese characters have a different width in GUI (IDLE of python or the IDE you are working on for example) but in CLI it appear like a "?" symbol and ALL characters in CLI have the same width, so it appear propperly in CLI but as "unknown character".

Answer (score 3):

Install `wcwidth` package may solve your problem. Seems that `tabulate` uses `wcwidth` to handle unicode strings.

```
$ pip install wcwidth
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried prettyable, tabulate... module for CJK env.. They have the alignment of CJK fonts problem in ASCII output.
But, one way can avoid the CJK fonts alignment problem that uses **html output** formation.

sample code:

```
import prettytable as pt

tb1=pt.PrettyTable()

tb1.padding_width = 5
tb1.field_names=[" 名稱", " 項目", " 數量", "單價", "總價"]
tb1.align[" 名稱"]="c"
tb1.align["項目"]="l"
tb1.align["數量"]="r"
tb1.align["單價"]="r"
tb1.align["總價"]="r"

for task in list1:
    tb1.add_row(task)
    
print(tb1.get_html_string())         #改寫成HTML 格式輸出, 避開中文對齊問題
```

[image]